# SegFault on application exit

Tags: c++, valgrind

I'm experiencing a weird and annoying problem with one of the application I use at work. The application is written in C++ and when the application terminates ( either the main function return or `exit` is called ), it crashes with a segmentation fault. The segmentation fault seems to be caused by double-freeing pointer in the basic_string class destructor. I cannot add the source code, but I can say that the app is extremely simple and I am not directly using any pointer in my code. The app is just calling a function from a library.

Valgrid identifies the following problem:

```
==5402== Invalid read of size 4
==5402==    at 0x549F05F: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() (atomicity.h:49)
==5402==    by 0x41D1BA4: ??? (in ../Functions.so)
==5402==    by 0x436D873: ??? (in ../Functions.so)
==5402==    by 0x967674: _dl_fini (in /lib/ld-2.12.so)
==5402==    by 0x9A7EAE: exit (in /lib/libc-2.12.so)
==5402==    by 0x810F8C2: main (Checker.C:146)
==5402==  Address 0x55ec808 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 15 free'd
==5402==    at 0x4007895: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:480)
==5402==    by 0x549EF67: std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&) (new_allocator.h:110)
==5402==    by 0x810F8C2: main (Checker.C:146)
==5402==
==5402== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==5402==    at 0x4007895: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:480)
==5402==    by 0x549EF67: std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&) (new_allocator.h:110)
==5402==    by 0x41D1BA4: ??? (in ..../Functions.so)
==5402==    by 0x436D873: ??? (in .../Functions.so)
==5402==    by 0x967674: _dl_fini (in /lib/ld-2.12.so)
==5402==    by 0x9A7EAE: exit (in /lib/libc-2.12.so)
==5402==    by 0x810F8C2: main (Checker.C:146)
==5402==  Address 0x55ec800 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 15 free'd
==5402==    at 0x4007895: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:480)
==5402==    by 0x549EF67: std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&) (new_allocator.h:110)
==5402==    by 0x810F8C2: main (Checker.C:146)
==5402==
```

The application is linked to both shared and static library. `Function.so` is a shared library which may contain some static code. This problem is related to the linking phase, because depending on the order on which libraries are linked to my executable the app may not crash.

I am really struggling to tackle this issue, any idea what could be the root cause of such issue? Any suggestion how to proceed to investigate this problem?

Comment: Can you look inside the library's code? Perhaps some static data has a buggy destructor or constructor.

Comment: Yes, I own the lib. I can look into it

Comment: upvoting only to balance whoever had enough time to downvote, but not enough to explain why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of this issue is a bug somewhere in your code. The bug can be anything. Wild pointer dereference, running off the end of the array, or any number of other myriad kinds of bugs. A bug in C++ code does not necessarily mean that the application will crash at that point, immediately. The application can continue executing, but crash at some later point when it tries to access the corrupted memory that resulted from the bug.

There is a bug somewhere in your code that likely results in memory corruption, which triggers this crash when the application terminates. You will need to find it, and fix it. Welcome to C++.

Comment: Any suggestion, tool I can use to help me in the process of finding the bug?

Comment: `valgrind` is often very good at finding these kinds of bugs. It won't always work, but will usually find them. The best tool is always one's own brain.